# Adding a timeout to a parallelized call in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, parallelism, timeout

I have a simple Bash script I am running to parallelize and automate the execution of a program written in Sage MATH:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..500}; do
  echo Spinning up threads...
  echo Round $i
  for j in {1..8}; do
    ../sage ./loader.sage.py &
  done
  wait
done 2>/dev/null
```

I would like to add a timeout so that on each thread, after 5 seconds,

```
../sage ./loader.sage.py &
```

will timeout, kill the thread, and continue execution. How would I go about doing this? Apologies in advance if this is a noob question, I can't seem to get the syntax right.
I am running this in a Ubuntu WSL. The program I am calling is written in Python and run through the Sage MATH interpreter which liaises to Singular.

Comment: `timeout 5 ../sage ./loader.sage.py &` As long as you have coreutils, but in that case you could probably simplify this whole thing with GNU parallel

Comment: I'm preparing to run this on a compute cluster and am trying to avoid dependencies, but I'll look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using GNU Parallel:

```
parallel --timeout 5 -j 8 -N0 ../sage ./loader.sage.py ::: {1..4000} 2>/dev/null
```

This will execute `../sage ./loader.sage.py` 4000 times, 8 jobs at a time, each with a timeout of 5 seconds

From the parallel man page:

```
--timeout duration
           Time out for command. If the command runs for longer than duration seconds it will get killed as per --termseq.
```

Note: This command replaces your entire loop.

Answer (score 0):

man timeout -- in my Linux Mint but you don't declare your OS.

```
timeout 5 ../sage ./loader.sage.py &
```

Added some debug to show processes start and stop. It seems possible your sage startup is disk-bound (maybe having to clear cache) and cannot use all the CPU available. As Python is (AFAIK) a just-in-time compile, that may be a bottleneck.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..3}; do
    echo Spinning up threads...
    echo Round $i
    for j in {1..3}; do
        timeout 1.5 sleep 60 &
    done
    echo "==== $( date '+%H:%M:%S.%N') Before"; jobs
    ps -f
    wait
    echo "==== $( date '+%H:%M:%S.%N') After"; jobs
    ps -f
    echo; timeout 1.0 sleep 0.2
done
```

Comment: I've seen this solution before, I'm not sure why but it seems to not work. I'll add some clarification to the original question, but my CPU usage drops from 100% to about 30% and doesn't move on.